# antlrworks2 testrig configuration

Tags: java, antlr, antlrworks

I am new to Antlr, now I am trying to test the sample code with antlrworks2

I already generated the recognizer with antlrworks2 like following:
[image]

In my testTxt.txt is just:

```
hello parrt
```

and when I run in TestRig :

[image]

The nullpointer error happens, and output always stay at compiling state.

[image]

[image]

I guess there are some configuration problem, but I can't find any hint about configuration with antlrworks2.

PS. The grammar is the same as the tutorial in official website
[image]

Comment: Please post the grammar. I had a similar issue with an infinite-recursion grammar.

Comment: @Mephy Added, I guess grammar is correct since it is just the sample tutorial code

Comment: `hello r` is not a valid rule.